# Updating text input state and AJAX search by same value lagging by one character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text input search bar to look up products and as I type in terms it makes an AJAX request to find the matches and sets those as the products state. However, it is lagging by one character. IE I type in "car" and it is searching for "ca", when I type in "cars" it searches with "car". I'm guessing it has something to do with how React setState works. Hints on how to solve this?

```
class ProductIndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      collection: null,
      products: this.props.products
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({term: event});
    this.searchProducts()
  }
  render() {
    function CreateItem(product) {
      return { 
        url: '/products/' + product.id, 
        attributeOne: product.title,
        attributeTwo: product.variants[0].variant_price,
        attributeThree: '5 prices from $8.99 to $13.99',
        media: <Thumbnail
                  source={product.main_image_src}
                  alt={product.title}
                  size="small"
                />
      }
    }
    function CollectionTitles(collection) {
      return collection.title
    }
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Layout.Section>
          <Card title="Online store dashboard" actions={[{content: 'Edit'}]} sectioned>
            <Card.Section>
              <Stack>
                <TextField 
                  value={this.state.term}
                  label="Keyword Search"
                  placeholder="Enter Term"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <Select
                  value= {this.state.collection}
                  label="Collection"
                  options={ this.props.collections.map(CollectionTitles) }
                  placeholder="Select"
                  //onChange={this.valueUpdater('collection')}
                  //onChange={this.searchProducts('collection')}
                />
              </Stack>
            </Card.Section>
            <Card.Section>
                <ResourceList
                  items={
                      this.state.products.map(CreateItem)
                  }
                  renderItem={(item, index) => {
                    return <ResourceList.Item key={index} {...item} className='Polaris-Card' />;
                  }}
                />
            </Card.Section>
          </Card>
        </Layout.Section>
      </Layout>
    ); 
  }
searchProducts() {
  console.log('In queryProducts');
  console.log('AJAX')
  $.ajax( {
    url: '/products/' + "?term=" + this.state.term, //+ "&collection=" + this.state.collection,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
      console.log(data)
    this.setState({ products: data });
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(data) {
    }.bind(this)
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `setState` function is asynchronous. So when you call `setState` then it does not set the state immediatly. And you are calling api call right after calling `setState` (i.e. when state is not updated yet). Thats why it is calling api without last letter.

The solution:: Pass a callback function to setState. That callback will be called when state is update. In that callback you can call your api like this

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({term: event}, () => {
      this.searchProducts()
    });
  }
```